# Azure DevOps Pipelines - Publish Test Results

Tags: angular, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I've followed all the steps in Publish Unit Test in this [article](https://tharaka-madhusanka.medium.com/publish-execute-angular-unit-tests-in-azure-devops-build-pipeline-with-code-test-unit-test-c32288d59e8d) but I have a problem which is

> ##[warning]No test result files matching **/testresults/unit-test-result.xml were found.

How do I solve it?
I think the difference between the path for JUnit XML test result in the Pipeline and the path in the `karma.conf.js` is the problem.

My Publish Test Results in devops

[image]

My `karma.conf.js`

```js
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

const path = require('path');

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '.',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      // require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
      captureConsole: Boolean(process.env.KARMA_ENABLE_CONSOLE),
    },
    // junitReporter: {
    //   outputDir: path.join(__dirname, './reports/junit/'),
    //   outputFile: 'TESTS-xunit.xml',
    //   useBrowserName: false,
    //   suite: '', // Will become the package name attribute in xml testsuite element
    // },
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: 'testresults/junit',
      outputFile: 'unit-test-result.xml',
      useBrowserName: false,
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      dir: path.join(__dirname, './reports/coverage'),
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
    },
    // reporters: ['progress', 'junit'],
    
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'junit'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    // Level of logging, can be: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true,
  });
};
```

Comment: How does your folder structure look in your local environment? check the file is written and in correct folder name

Answer (score 1):

The *Test results files* path is not quite right.

Your karma configuration will produce a results file at

> testresults/junit/unit-test-result.xml

but your search path, `**/testresults/unit-test-result.xml`, won't match that, because it is excluding the junit folder.

If you change the search path to `**/testresults/junit/unit-test-result.xml`, for example, that should work.